# C struct and union together

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I have the following code.

```
struct Node {
  struct Node *next;
  char type[12];
  union {
    struct A *a;
  };
};

int main() {
  char *x[6];
  x[1] = "a";
  x[2] = "bc";
  x[3] = "bf";
  x[4] = "bd";
  x[5] = "ab";
  x[6] = "b";

  struct Node *new = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

  struct A*a = (struct A*) malloc(sizeof(struct A));
  *a->a = x[1];
  *a->b = x[2];
  *a->c = x[3];
  *a->d = x[4];
  new.a = a;
}
```

I am trying to give a value to each property of a but I am constantly getting errors as follows.

```
struct or union expected at  //*a->c= x[3];//
```

I also tried this

```
*a.c= x[3];
 a.c = x[3]
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: What is `x`? Please create a proper [mcve] to show us. And don't forget to show us the *complete* and *full* build output of that MCVE.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/ -- `a` is a pointer to your `struct A`. So to change its elements should be `a->a = someChar`. Also, as @Someprogrammerdude pointed out, `x` stores elements of a given type. Since the elements in `a` have different types, it's never going to work out.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude are you sure? It is singly linked list which is heteregenous not even an array.

Comment: A union that only has one member makes no sense.

Comment: @n.m. it does not matter that is not the point here

Comment: Now we can see that `x` is an *array* of pointers to `char` (i.e. an array of strings). And that makes ***none*** of your initialization of the structure `a` make any sense. For example `*a->a = x[1]` is equal to `a->a[0] = x[1]`, that is you assign the second pointer of `x` to the ***single character*** `a->a[0]`. If your compiler doesn't should warnings at you for that then you need to enable more warnings.

Comment: The struct pointer syntax `a->b` is shorthand for `(*a).b` Which is to say that you don't need the `*` when you're using `->`. But that's the least of your problems. `x` is an array of character pointers, and none of the member variables of `a` are character pointers, so none of the elements of array `x` can be assigned to member variables of `a`.

Comment: If it's not the point, don't include it in the question. Your problem has nothing to do with unions. `a->c` is an integer. `*a->c` has as much sense as `*42`. You also have a problem in `x[6] = "b";`. Array indices start at 0. There's no `x[6]` in a 6-element array.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `*a->c` is equal to `*(a->c)`. That is you attempt to dereference the `c` member.

The error you get is because `a->c` is not a pointer or an array. You can't use the dereference operator on something that's not a pointer or an array.

You should get the same error for attempting to dereference `a->d` as well.

You should probably not use dereferencing here at all (i.e. you just remove the asterisk).

Answer (score 0):

The following cause compiler errors in the code shown in the question:

- Using `sizeof(struct A)` while `struct A` is not completely defined.
- Using `a->a`, `a->b`, `a->c`, and `a->d` while `struct A` is not completely defined.
- Using `new.a`, since `new` is declared to be a pointer in `struct Node *new`.

The last of these could produce the error message stated in the question, that a struct or union is expected. The line the question states produces this message, `a->c= x[3];`, should not, as no operator expecting a struct or union is used in that statement except for `->`, which correctly receives a pointer to a struct (albeit incompletely defined).

Therefore, I suspect the code getting the message or the location for the message has been reported incorrectly in the question.

Additionally, `char *x[6]; … x[6] = "b";` is wrong; when an array is defined with `[6[`, its valid indices run from 0 to 5, not 6.